# How to start at a index but without missing any items in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am learning JS and have a task to complete which is quite confusing. The task is to giving a index to start from and include the remainders or the the items missing in the array, as well as to display them in angular. This is what i have

```
const arr = ["a", "b" ,"c" ,"d"]

const startIndex = 2:

let arr2 = arr.slice(startIndex, arr.length)

Output

["c","d"]

// a and b are ignore and don't see a way to display them accordingly
```

The tasks is to start let's say at index 2 through the last item and include items a and b which are the items missing when using slice method

Comment: So it is doing what you told it to do - starting with index 2 The third element) is "c" - not sure what your confusion is.  Do you mean you want the elements in the array PRIOR to that not STARTING with that?  Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @Alexander Nenashev, I understand what you're saying ,however, Since the startIndex = 2, the slice method would start at "c" but it would leave out items or elements prior 'c'. The task is to include those missing items as well. For instance, 
The method would slice the array starting at index 2 -> `['c','d']` but what happens with the other missing items 'a' and 'b'?

`["c","d","a","b"]

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example with your code above:

**JS**

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const startIndex = 2;
let arr2 = [...arr.slice(startIndex), ...arr.slice(0, startIndex)];
console.log(arr2);
```

The **...** is the spread operator, it allows an iterable (like an array expression) to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected.

**Angular Example**:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr2">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the original array copied twice:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const startIndex = 2;

const result = [...arr, ...arr]
  .slice(startIndex, startIndex + arr.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since I feel this is for educational purposes thought it would be nice to have something without any inbuilt operators. Here is an alternative approach to your case without any inbuilt operators in javascript.**

```js
function customSliceAndMoveItems(array, startIndex) {
  var result = [];
  
  
  for (var i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  
  for (var j = 0; j < startIndex; j++) {
    result.push(array[j]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(customSliceAndMoveItems(["a", "b", "c", "d"],2))
```

**In case considering the performance aspect you can optimize the above code while using the Array `slice()` operator and Array `concat()` operator.**

```js
function customSliceAndMoveItems(array, startIndex) {
  return array.slice(startIndex).concat(array.slice(0, startIndex));
}

console.log(customSliceAndMoveItems(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

**When it comes to angular you can iterate it over the template directly as follows :**

```
<h1 *ngFor="let item of getArray1(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)">
  {{ item }}
</h1>
```

**Please find the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgnons?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).**